# Variables for colors in interface builder

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

I have a project that I need to change overall color themes in the app. A lot of my UI elements are built through Interface Builder in Xcode 6.1. I need to set colors as variables in interface builder, so if I set a preprocessor telling the app to use a certain scheme then the colors will change in interface builder. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this with interface builder, however there is a way that you can set appearance properties in code for many IOS UI elements that will then apply globally. As an example see the following snippet of code:

```
UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()
UITableView.appearance().sectionIndexColor = UIColor.grayColor();

UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

The code sets a the default tint and bar color for all the UIToolbars, separator and section index colors for all UITableViews, and appearance properties for all the UINavigation views in my app..

You could use `#if` to set the appearance differently depending on the environment variables set in the compiler.

If you want to find out more about how this works Id suggest reading Apples documentation on UIAppearance properties here:
[UIAppearance Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html)

Comment: This is not helping at all. If some one asks a specific question like this they most probably know about appearance... What if you have 2 kinds of labels (headers and texts) and want to change the color of all headers? Then you cannot just change the label appearance!

Answer (score 1):

Color variables are awesome, I wish xcode had this too.

Turns out you can add a color variables feature.

This xcode plugin, called [Suggested Colors](https://github.com/jwaitzel/SuggestedColors), let's you build and use a palette of colors in Interface Builder. It uses a `plist` file, So I think you could read that in code and have a color palette shared between code and IB this way. Looks promising. Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work on xcode 6.3.2. Hope it gets fixed.